# How can I create a helper function to change image using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to create an **imgLoader** function that take in 3 arguements :

- btn : the btn that got click
- img : the specific img that will be load on
- imgPath : the path to the img that I want to load

I also want the btn to be optional, so I check if btn is true.

Here is what I come up with :

```
function imgLoader( btn, img, imgPath) {

    if (btn) {
        $btnBiDefault.removeClass('btn-bi-default-clicked');
        btn.addClass('btn-bi-default-clicked');
    }

    img.attr('src', imgPath);

}
```

I tried to call **imgLoader** in one of my click funtion :

```
$name.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    imgLoader({
        img: $img,
        imgPath: '/path-to-img/image.png'
    });
});
```

I got 0 error, not even warning on my .js file.
I couldn't get my img to load.

I keep getting :

> Uncaught TypeError: btn.addClass is not a function

Can someone please give me a hint ?

Comment: FYI, making the first argument of a function optional, isn't really a very good idea ?

Comment: `btn.addClass is not a function` means that `btn` doesn't have access to a method named `addClass()`, which means that `btn` is not a jQuery object. Where does it come from, what *should* it be?

Comment: You can't make the first argument optional, how would the function know that you didn't pass the first argument and instead passed the image as the first argument

Comment: You are calling imgLoader with an object, but your function is defined as needing 3 different arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably pass an object instead of three separate variables. This allows you to have greater control of what you're able to send to the function. For example, you could call your imgLoader function with no button: `imgLoader({img: "...", imgPath: "..."})` or with a button: `imgLoader({btn: $(ele), img: "...", imgPath: "..."})`.

The order of the elements within the object you're passing is irrelevant, and can be called using dot notation: `args.item`.

Try something like this:

```js
function imgLoader(args) {
    "use strict";
    if (typeof args.btn !== "undefined") {
        // Do things with your button here.
    }

    $(args.img).attr('src', args.imgPath);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onClick="imgLoader({btn: this, img: '#imgID', imgPath: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/cats'})">Get a cat</button>
<img id="imgID" alt="A random cat." />
```

Comment: You really should take the time to explain your answer, that way the posted code is, or might be, applicable to others in future.

Comment: Good idea. I'll add a bit more detail. =)

Comment: You already are in your OP. I added a bit more detail in my post. If you don't see it you could try refreshing.

Comment: Added a more detailed example so you can further see what's going on.